# How to update a Recycler view with live data inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, androidx

I want to update my Recycler View, so that whenever I delete a row from a table in a database, it updates the Recycler View at once without refreshing the fragment.

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?
    {

        var binding:FragmentDisplayBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_display,container,false)

        var view:View = binding.root

        var new_task : FloatingActionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.add_newTask)





        var db = Room.databaseBuilder(context!!,tasksDb:: class.java,"mydb").allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        db.task().getAll().observe(this, Observer {
            this.myAdapter = myAdapter(it)
            recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
            recyclerView.layoutManager = viewManager
        })
```

I believe I should not use the .observe() in the onCreateView() method. What changes should I implement in the code ??

Comment: Since you have live data already implemented, it would be nice to implement a `DiffUtil`. [Read about DiffUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil). TLDR; It calculates the differences in your list and updates accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried to find some example solutions on the Internet. There must be one, but couldn't find any. I find many of them are too short or too detailed. So I will drop here just exactly what you need. There is a standardized pattern involving `RecyclerView` + `LiveData`, so just follow this pattern for all your `RecyclerView` + `LiveData` usages.

**Fragment:**

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    ...

    val recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    val myAdapter = MyAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
    // recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context) // You need this only if you haven't set it in xml

    db.task().getAll().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        myAdapter.submitList(it)
    })
}
```

Few important changes made here:

- You must `.observe()` in `onCreateView()`. Not just for this specific case, but in general you will never need to call `.observe()` in any other places if you are using `LiveData` correctly.
- `viewLifecycleOwner` is the correct `LifecycleOwner` to use for observing a `LiveData`. (Unless you create a custom one.)
- Depends on the use case but generally instantiate one adapter per `RecyclerView`, even if your data changes over time. You should swap the data, not the whole adapter.

**MyAdapter:**

`MyAdapter` should implement the `.submitList()` function that will be used by the view

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    val myData = mutableListOf<Data>()

    fun submitList(newData: List<Data>) {
        myData.clear()
        myData.addAll(newData)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Note that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is the one actually signals the adapter to update the view.

**Improvements:**

I think above solution is good enough for your problem, given that your list is not too big or too frequently updated. If you want further improvement in performance and/or readability, explore following:

- Use [Paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) library to paginate long or infinite list.
- Diff in a worker thread using DiffUtil as suggested in the comment.
- [Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) library to reduce some boiler plates

Comment: If I have written such a code, do you think internally inside recyclerview adapater, if I do `currentData = myData[position]` and then for example, change data on clicklistner in `onBindViewHolder` by doing `currentData.name=1000`. Will this line trigger live data too?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help.

To refresh your items in recycler you need to use below code

**myAdapter. notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerview.setAdapter(myAdapter);**

In your case write this method immediately after your logic to delete item of recycler view.

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` should not be encouraged because it is super inefficient. It forces the recycler view to drop current items and redraw, hence using more resources. A better and newer approach is to use a `DiffUtil`.

Comment: Hi, Taseer Ahmad. After reading from the link you have mentioned above, I totally agree with you that DiffUtil will be really good solution.   Thanks.